# Как заменить input на просто текст и наоборот?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `input`, при вводе правильного значения он превращается из поля ввода в то число которое было введено пользователем

```js
$(".inputA").change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() < a) {
        $(this).css("border", "5px solid red");
      } else if ($(this).val() == a) {
        $(this).css("border", "5px solid green");
        drawArcB();
        $(".inputB").css("display", "block");
      }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="inputA">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше подписаться на событие blur.
Что значит наоборот? У вас уже текст вместо поля.

```js
const a = 546;
$(".inputA").blur(function() {
      if ($(this).val() < a) {
        $(this).css("border", "5px solid red");
      } else if ($(this).val() == a) {
        $('.wrapper').text($(this).val());
        //$(this).css("border", "5px solid green");
        //drawArcB();
        //$(".inputB").css("display", "block");
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<input type="number" class="inputA">
</div>
```

Comment: Убрать текст и поставить туда инпут.
Например у меня написано 4+1=? вместо вопроса инпут должен появится.

Comment: Для этого есть метод .html('<input>')

Comment: Я попробовал прописать с таймаутом.
setTimeout(function () {
            $('.divA').text($(this).val())
            }, 2000
        );
Выводит ошибку Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined. Можете подсказать в чем может быть ошибка ?

Comment: А все понял, он теряет $(this).val() при таймауте, с чем связано не знаю....

Answer (score 0):

Я правильно понял суть задачи?

Если да, то можете использовать этот вариант, но не стоит.. Я очень хочу спать и написал код не особо обдумав.

Это больше "подсказка" для других :D

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  var elemInput = $('.input'),
      elemText = $('.text');
  if(elemInput.hasClass('hide')) {
    // Если сейчас показан текст
    elemInput.removeClass('hide'); // Показываем инпут
    elemText.addClass('hide'); // Прячем текст
    $(this).text('Сохранить'); // Меняем название кнопки чтобы пользователям было понятнее
  } else if(elemText.hasClass('hide')) {
    // Если сейчас показан инпут
    var InputVal = elemInput.find('input').val(); // Получаем значения инпута
    elemText.text(InputVal); // Вставляем значение в текст
    elemText.removeClass('hide'); // Показываем текст
    elemInput.addClass('hide'); // Прячем инпут
    $(this).text('Изменить'); // Меняем название кнопки чтобы пользователям было понятнее
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="input hide">
  <input type="number" value="0">
</div>
<div class="text">0</div>
<button>Изменить</button>
```

Comment: Лол, прочитал комменты к другому ответу, и понял, что совсем не то.. Сорян :D